# Kubernetes operator-sdk : How to delete controller?

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

We have developed a bunch of controllers and APIs, we need to delete some controllers but we are unable to find a way to delete the API and controllers.

We looked at the available options but no flag to delete the apis.

```
operator-sdk --help
CLI tool for building Kubernetes extensions and tools.

Usage:
  operator-sdk [flags]
  operator-sdk [command]

Examples:
The first step is to initialize your project:
    operator-sdk init [--plugins=<PLUGIN KEYS> [--project-version=<PROJECT VERSION>]]

<PLUGIN KEYS> is a comma-separated list of plugin keys from the following table
and <PROJECT VERSION> a supported project version for these plugins.

                         Plugin keys | Supported project versions
-------------------------------------+----------------------------
 ansible.sdk.operatorframework.io/v1 |                          3
    declarative.go.kubebuilder.io/v1 |                       2, 3
                go.kubebuilder.io/v2 |                       2, 3
                go.kubebuilder.io/v3 |                          3
    helm.sdk.operatorframework.io/v1 |                          3
  kustomize.common.kubebuilder.io/v1 |                          3
 quarkus.javaoperatorsdk.io/v1-alpha |                          3

For more specific help for the init command of a certain plugins and project version
configuration please run:
    operator-sdk init --help --plugins=<PLUGIN KEYS> [--project-version=<PROJECT VERSION>]

Default plugin keys: "go.kubebuilder.io/v3"
Default project version: "3"


Available Commands:
  alpha            Alpha-stage subcommands
  bundle           Manage operator bundle metadata
  cleanup          Clean up an Operator deployed with the 'run' subcommand
  completion       Load completions for the specified shell
  create           Scaffold a Kubernetes API or webhook
  edit             Update the project configuration
  generate         Invokes a specific generator
  help             Help about any command
  init             Initialize a new project
  olm              Manage the Operator Lifecycle Manager installation in your cluster
  pkgman-to-bundle Migrates packagemanifests to bundles
  run              Run an Operator in a variety of environments
  scorecard        Runs scorecard
  version          Print the operator-sdk version

Flags:
  -h, --help                     help for operator-sdk
      --plugins strings          plugin keys to be used for this subcommand execution
      --project-version string   project version (default "3")
      --verbose                  Enable verbose logging
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an automated way to remove APIs via the operator-sdk.

There are a couple ways to do it. If you're operator is fairly simple, you could just scaffold a new operator and copy the code you want into it.

Otherwise, you'll have to remove it by hand. I created a dummy operator, commited it, and then added a new API to get this diff which can be used to see what you'll need to delete. (This is using the `master` branch, it may be different depending on the version you are using.)

```
diff --git a/PROJECT b/PROJECT
index ca36be5..0bb71be 100644
--- a/PROJECT
+++ b/PROJECT
@@ -16,4 +16,13 @@ resources:
   kind: Memcached
   path: github.com/example/memcached-operator/api/v1alpha1
   version: v1alpha1
+- api:
+    crdVersion: v1
+    namespaced: true
+  controller: true
+  domain: example.com
+  group: cache
+  kind: Memcached2
+  path: github.com/example/memcached-operator/api/v1alpha1
+  version: v1alpha1
 version: "3"
diff --git a/api/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go b/api/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go
index 7730cf5..8211ded 100644
--- a/api/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go
+++ b/api/v1alpha1/zz_generated.deepcopy.go
@@ -51,6 +51,95 @@ func (in *Memcached) DeepCopyObject() runtime.Object {
    return nil
 }
 
+// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
+func (in *Memcached2) DeepCopyInto(out *Memcached2) {
+   *out = *in
+   out.TypeMeta = in.TypeMeta
+   in.ObjectMeta.DeepCopyInto(&out.ObjectMeta)
+   out.Spec = in.Spec
+   out.Status = in.Status
+}
+
+// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new Memcached2.
+func (in *Memcached2) DeepCopy() *Memcached2 {
+   if in == nil {
+       return nil
+   }
+   out := new(Memcached2)
+   in.DeepCopyInto(out)
+   return out
+}
+
+// DeepCopyObject is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new runtime.Object.
+func (in *Memcached2) DeepCopyObject() runtime.Object {
+   if c := in.DeepCopy(); c != nil {
+       return c
+   }
+   return nil
+}
+
+// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
+func (in *Memcached2List) DeepCopyInto(out *Memcached2List) {
+   *out = *in
+   out.TypeMeta = in.TypeMeta
+   in.ListMeta.DeepCopyInto(&out.ListMeta)
+   if in.Items != nil {
+       in, out := &in.Items, &out.Items
+       *out = make([]Memcached2, len(*in))
+       for i := range *in {
+           (*in)[i].DeepCopyInto(&(*out)[i])
+       }
+   }
+}
+
+// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new Memcached2List.
+func (in *Memcached2List) DeepCopy() *Memcached2List {
+   if in == nil {
+       return nil
+   }
+   out := new(Memcached2List)
+   in.DeepCopyInto(out)
+   return out
+}
+
+// DeepCopyObject is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new runtime.Object.
+func (in *Memcached2List) DeepCopyObject() runtime.Object {
+   if c := in.DeepCopy(); c != nil {
+       return c
+   }
+   return nil
+}
+
+// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
+func (in *Memcached2Spec) DeepCopyInto(out *Memcached2Spec) {
+   *out = *in
+}
+
+// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new Memcached2Spec.
+func (in *Memcached2Spec) DeepCopy() *Memcached2Spec {
+   if in == nil {
+       return nil
+   }
+   out := new(Memcached2Spec)
+   in.DeepCopyInto(out)
+   return out
+}
+
+// DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
+func (in *Memcached2Status) DeepCopyInto(out *Memcached2Status) {
+   *out = *in
+}
+
+// DeepCopy is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, creating a new Memcached2Status.
+func (in *Memcached2Status) DeepCopy() *Memcached2Status {
+   if in == nil {
+       return nil
+   }
+   out := new(Memcached2Status)
+   in.DeepCopyInto(out)
+   return out
+}
+
 // DeepCopyInto is an autogenerated deepcopy function, copying the receiver, writing into out. in must be non-nil.
 func (in *MemcachedList) DeepCopyInto(out *MemcachedList) {
    *out = *in
diff --git a/config/crd/kustomization.yaml b/config/crd/kustomization.yaml
index 8b7bb5b..5d83219 100644
--- a/config/crd/kustomization.yaml
+++ b/config/crd/kustomization.yaml
@@ -3,17 +3,20 @@
 # It should be run by config/default
 resources:
 - bases/cache.example.com_memcacheds.yaml
+- bases/cache.example.com_memcached2s.yaml
 #+kubebuilder:scaffold:crdkustomizeresource
 
 patchesStrategicMerge:
 # [WEBHOOK] To enable webhook, uncomment all the sections with [WEBHOOK] prefix.
 # patches here are for enabling the conversion webhook for each CRD
 #- patches/webhook_in_memcacheds.yaml
+#- patches/webhook_in_memcached2s.yaml
 #+kubebuilder:scaffold:crdkustomizewebhookpatch
 
 # [CERTMANAGER] To enable cert-manager, uncomment all the sections with [CERTMANAGER] prefix.
 # patches here are for enabling the CA injection for each CRD
 #- patches/cainjection_in_memcacheds.yaml
+#- patches/cainjection_in_memcached2s.yaml
 #+kubebuilder:scaffold:crdkustomizecainjectionpatch
 
 # the following config is for teaching kustomize how to do kustomization for CRDs.
diff --git a/config/samples/kustomization.yaml b/config/samples/kustomization.yaml
index 42654aa..9c62d32 100644
--- a/config/samples/kustomization.yaml
+++ b/config/samples/kustomization.yaml
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 ## Append samples you want in your CSV to this file as resources ##
 resources:
 - cache_v1alpha1_memcached.yaml
+- cache_v1alpha1_memcached2.yaml
 #+kubebuilder:scaffold:manifestskustomizesamples
diff --git a/controllers/suite_test.go b/controllers/suite_test.go
index 97d4bfb..ffce919 100644
--- a/controllers/suite_test.go
+++ b/controllers/suite_test.go
@@ -65,6 +65,9 @@ var _ = BeforeSuite(func() {
    err = cachev1alpha1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)
    Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
 
+   err = cachev1alpha1.AddToScheme(scheme.Scheme)
+   Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
+
    //+kubebuilder:scaffold:scheme
 
    k8sClient, err = client.New(cfg, client.Options{Scheme: scheme.Scheme})
diff --git a/main.go b/main.go
index b2bedfd..443397e 100644
--- a/main.go
+++ b/main.go
@@ -85,6 +85,13 @@ func main() {
        setupLog.Error(err, "unable to create controller", "controller", "Memcached")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
+   if err = (&controllers.Memcached2Reconciler{
+       Client: mgr.GetClient(),
+       Scheme: mgr.GetScheme(),
+   }).SetupWithManager(mgr); err != nil {
+       setupLog.Error(err, "unable to create controller", "controller", "Memcached2")
+       os.Exit(1)
+   }
    //+kubebuilder:scaffold:builder
 
    if err := mgr.AddHealthzCheck("healthz", healthz.Ping); err != nil {
```

I'm not sure if this is something that we could add to the operator-sdk right now, but it would be worth filing an issue, which we will discuss at our triage meeting. https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=feature-request.md&title=